# Best way to clean butter from a knife

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

Butter doesn't clean off of silverware very easy.  Every time I finish buttering bread, I'm left with a knife covered in butter which needs to be cleaned.  I can't just run it under the sink unless I wait for the hot water to work its way through the house.  I don't want to waste a whole paper towel for the job.

So far I've been ripping corners off of paper towels to clean the knife without being wasteful.  Is there a better way to clean butter off of a knife?

Comment: Your tongue has approx 36 degree temperature. Try licking the knife to separate the butter.

Comment: If your knife is "covered in butter" try using a little less of it. It'll be less wasteful and easier to leave on your bread instead of going down the drain with the soap or taking more paper with it to a land-fill.

Answer (score 7):

If I only used the knife for buttering bread, I clean the knife on the crust of the bread. This way (almost) all butter will be removed from the knife.

Answer (score 1):

Are you drinking tea or diluted coffee with that bread?
If so, pour some excess boiling water over the knife and  the butter will wash off immediately.

Comment: Rule of thumb guys: If you downvote something, please say why. It helps the person learn what they did wrong.

Comment: Actually, and although I somewhat agree with you.. It is in fact **not** a rule of thumb. Downvoters don't have to explain their votes @DeltaEscher

Comment: I still don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: +1 for mentioning what should be common courteousness but isn't, here. It discourages new visitors and degrades the quality of the whole site. It should be a requirement.

Comment: @JustDoIt A Rule Of Thumb is a good thing to do—a good practice, a suggestion, something that helps—not a requirement, per se. For that reason, when/if you downvote, PLEASE INDICATE WHY so we can improve questions, answers, attitudes, and the site in general.

Comment: It's a suggestion, not a rule @Stan there's a difference. Voters are not obligated to say why did they downvoted or upvoted a post

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a bit of flour. It helps clean grease off of most things, and it can also be used to shine stainless steel. Also consider using a rag to wipe off dirty dishes. A rag has an advantage over paper towels in that it can be reused and washed.

Comment: well .. paper towels "can" be washed/reused .. O.o  http://www.mightybargainhunter.com/reusing-paper-towels-hmmmm/  (but I'd probably go with the rag myself anyway .. lol )

Answer (score 0):

Leave the knife with the rest of your dirty dishes, so you can clean them all in one big batch. That's much more efficient in both time and energy than cleaning them one at a time.

Comment: or just use the international symbol for "I might make another sandwich - not sure yet."  ... https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/5d/8a/44/5d8a44cc7627aae741b5c0a823aefd07.jpg   ;)

Comment: @Ditto I tried that once.  Due to an unfortunate accident regarding how conscious I am each morning when I make sandwiches, the result was 7 knives all nicely balanced on the side of the sink =)

Answer (score 0):

We have a dual basin sink. On one side I will leave a small amount of water with anti-bacterial dish detergent. Leave a sponge in the water for when you need it. This sponge can be used for cleaning up anything that isn't too oily or dirty, and won't smell due to the anti-bacterial agent in the soap.

Alternatively, you can use a microfibre cloth ie. Enjo. As long as the butter is still cold, it will wipe off easily.